# Can't detect GPU on tensorflow docker container launched from Pycharm

Tags: docker, tensorflow, pycharm, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to run a simple tensorflow example using the tensorflow provided gpu-enabled docker image, from within the Pycharm IDE. Everything works except that when I run it, tensorflow does not detect GPU from the container and defaults back to `CPU` :

```
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:318] failed call to cuInit:
```

Running:
Ubuntu 18.04.3
Docker 19.03.3
latest version of NVIDIA docker support as per : https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker

I have set up my Pycharm project with the remote interpreter feature to run the  image:tensorflow:latest-gpu

If I run the container from the command line with:

```
docker run --gpus all --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu nvidia-smi
```

I get this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.26       Driver Version: 430.26       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:41:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 28%   26C    P8     9W / 250W |    443MiB / 11177MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

..which tells me that the docker install, the image, and the nvidia docker support are all ok.

Now when Pycharm runs the container, it does NOT include "--gpus all" command line option.

If I run the same command above without the --gpus all parameter:

```
docker run --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu nvidia-smi
```

I get:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"nvidia-smi\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

So this would point to Pycharm not adding a flag as the culprit.

However, according to documentation at : https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/ (bottom section on GPU)
the environment variable NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all should accomplish the same thing. I confirmed this environment variable does get set even without the --gpus all param.

Additionally, there does not seem to be a way to add additional command line params from within Pycharm. So I am stuck. I feel that this setup is not too exotic and hope that I am missing something basic.

Comment: I am in the same boat. Have you found a solution?

Comment: unfortunately no, I ended up installing CUDA locally and setting up a local venv in pycharm. It worked well

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using Visual Code.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with pycharm and pytorch. Not sure why it happens, but I found a workaround for now, by making the following call when the script starts:

```
import os
os.system('nvidia-smi')
```

PS: the error I encountered was

> RuntimeError: Unexpected error from cudaGetDeviceCount(). Did you run some cuda functions before calling NumCudaDevices() that might have already set an error? Error 803: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination